# AWS Elasticsearch Bulk Insert Latency Increased drastically

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am using AWS Elasticsearch on a **t2.small node and 10gb EBS volume**. Every 5 minutes I am indexing about 5000 documents*. For each document I am manually passing the unique ID. Since most of the documents gets updated so **for almost all documents there could be version 2 or 3**.

It is also worth mentioning that everyday I am running a `delete_by_query` operation to delete documents older than one week.

Generally the latency for bulk insert is less than 1 second. But suddenly today after two weeks of testing within just few hours the latency increased up to **3 minutes just to bulk insert 5000 documents**.

I am using elasticsearch-py and awsauth.

I checked the AWS Cluster health statistics. It seems the Old Garbage Collection Time increased drastically since the problem of bulk insert latency stated. It appears there could be correlation between these.

[image]

How to deal with this issue? Is this because of maintaining multiple versions of the documents or use of deletion by query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't particularly surprising but it's going to be hard to give you a full answer simply because there are so many variables. Some things to consider:

1. Reindexing documents is very expensive since it involves a delete first
2. As indexes get bigger the overhead of performing segment merges also goes up
3. As indexes get bigger, maintaining doc values and global ordinals gets more expensive
4. You are running on burstable t2 instances and so may be running out of CPU or IO credits
5. You don't mention doing optimization/force-merges which *may* help if you have lots of deleted/outdated documents

Comment: How often should I run forcemerge? It appears to block insertion operation.

Comment: forcemerge does not block insertion and the deciding on when is very load dependent.